# hidden field how to remove last part of url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove GET parameters from urls:

```
http://localhost/fadt/admin/edit_country.php?id=7
```

I want my URLs to become:

```
http://localhost/fadt/admin/edit_country
```

here is how links are currently generated:

```
<button onClick="location.href='edit_country?id=<?php echo $row['COUNTRY_ID']; ?>'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

Comment: Don't know if I understand the question. You want to remove it from something you typed in?

Comment: you need htaccess for that - https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: i want to remove id value in url

Comment: If it's not on your url it wont be send to you server. If you want to send it to your server but not showing it on the url use a form to send a post request, it will cause more trouble than showing an id on the url but it hides the value from the url.

Comment: Use a form with POST instead of GET.

Comment: can u please give that to me..my code as follows:
countries.php
<button onClick="location.href ='edit_country?id=<?php echo $row['COUNTRY_ID']; ?>'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>

Comment: If you don't include the variable ( 7 in above code ) then how will the script (edit_country.php ) know which record it is to edit??

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a button use an HTML form with the POST method.

Something like:

```
<form action="edit_country.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['COUNTRY_ID'];?>" name="id" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"/>
</form>
```

in place of

```
<button onClick="location.href='edit_country?id=<?php echo $row['COUNTRY_ID']; ?>'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

Then on `edit_country.php` use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

This `id` can be manipulated just as easily as your button value so make sure you are authenticating executing user has permissions to perform action.

Update, using button:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['COUNTRY_ID'];?>" name="id" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: working but can we replace any other button instead of submit

Comment: Do you mean use `button` element in place of `input`, or something else?

Comment: yes...because if i use submit button design is changing

Comment: use button type submit `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>`

Comment: IE doesn't agree with you and defaults to button, I believe webkit does the same but I might be wrong. In any case it wont hurt to declare the type

Comment: IE usually doesn't agree with me (I'm mac based). I left `type` in my answer because I wasn't sure of IE's actions. I'll remove last comment though to not confuse OP. Webkit does support it without attribute.

Comment: @arun any luck with this now?

Comment: Do your `form`s have some style set to them? That's the only I think would affect it. This was a PHP question, I don't design much.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear the question but i think u need this

```
<?php

 $a =  explode('?','http://localhost/fadt/admin/edit_country.php?id=7');
echo rtrim($a[0], '.php')
 ?>
```